# Beamer, adding logo to frame title

Tags: beamer, align

I'm trying to add a logo to a frametitle of a specific page but I don't know how to align it.

This is my code (Madrid theme):

```
  \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos \includegraphics[height=0.45cm,right]{UTDT1.jpg}}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

But instead of looking like two lines, I need the text to be aligned with the logo. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you give.

Comment: Which package adds the `right` key to `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I'm using \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not only "looking like two lines", but your code indeed produces two lines. To prevent this, you can manually specify how far the image should be pushed to the right.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos \includegraphics[height=0.45cm,right=7.8cm]{example-image}}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The tricky part was getting the right width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\makebox[\framewidth]{Tabla de contenidos \hfill\includegraphics[height=0.45cm]{example-image}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]