# Keep frame title position fixed while adding logo to frame title

Tags: beamer, positioning, frame-title

I am studying the answers to this question [Beamer, adding logo to frame title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443588/beamer-adding-logo-to-frame-title)
The solutions use  `height=0.45cm` in which case everything is fine. I considered this height too small, so I enlarged it. However, this fix causes the frame title to jump out of its place.

How can I change the logo size while keeping the frame title position fixed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  introduction
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos \includegraphics[height=0.8cm,right=7.8cm]{example-image}}
  abc
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can use `valign=t` option when including the image. This will fix the title at the top of the image, no matter how large the image gets. I have made the image larger to show the difference.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  introduction
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos \includegraphics[height=3cm,right=7.8cm, valign=t]{example-image}}
  abc
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]